# optimal search algorithm without admissible heuristic

Tags: algorithm, search, a-star

Please forgive me if I'm not using the correct terms or have overlooked an existing solution. I'm not experienced in search algorithms and the theories behind it. I just would like to solve a problem.

I've previously used what I was told to be the A* algorithm to solve a different problem. But reading up on it I've realized that what I learned is not *quite* what wikipedia tells me.

What I learned was:

- Start at your origin node
- Open a new solution for each path you can take
- Recursively create a new subsolution for each path you can take from there
- When you arrive at the same place with multiple solutions, drop those who took longer than the fastest

Now if I understand wikipedia correctly, this is what I was supposed to do:

- Start at your origin node
- Open a new solution for each path you can take
- Order the solutions by "cost of path taken" + "estimated cost to target"
- Take cheapest solution and create subsolutions for each possible path
- order those solutions into the others then rinse repeat

I can see how this would help with not calculating quite as many solutions but my problem is that I see no possiblity to create an "optimistic" estimate.

I'm not searching for a path on a geographical map. I'm trying to find the best sequence of actions. There's a minimum sequence of - say - ABCDEFGH. You cannot do F before E but repeating previous actions in particilar ordering might make later actions more efficient.

**Do I need a different search algorithm? Do I do what I originally learned and just live with the fact that doing more work is the price for not having a good heuristic function?**

I believe my teacher recognized this problem. And what I learned was simply A* with a heuristic function of f(n) = 0.

Comment: A* without an admissable heuristic is basically BFS, which in the worst case will explore every possible state. Will find a solution, but worst case is still brute force.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not searching for a path on a geographical map. I'm trying to find
>   the best sequence of actions. There's a minimum sequence of - say -
>   ABCDEFGH. You cannot do F before E but repeating previous actions in
>   particular ordering might make later actions more efficient.

It is not clear to me whether you can repeat one action, i.e., a solution is ABCDEFGH, but would ABBBBCDEFGH be possible?

If not, then you might be able to have A* algorithm, implemented like this:

```
1. At some stage (say the first, "empty"), you have one of several actions
   available.
2. The cost of going from Empty City to A City is the cost of action A.

3. The cost of going from Empty City to B city is the cost of action B.
```

When you've reached B, the cost of doing C is *constant* (if it is not, then you can't use A* as is) and you insert the cost of going from B City to C City as the cost of C.

So you can handle the case in which an action has different costs, **provided that this difference is completely described by the previous state**. For example, if you can only do C if you have done A or B, and the cost of C is 5 and 8, you enter the "distance" between A and C as 5, and B to C as 8.

If the cost of, say, D depends on the two previous states, you can still use a more complicated A* implementation where you define the virtual "cities" BC, AB and AC, and the distance from BC to D is "the cost of D having done B and C", and so on. The cost of reaching BC from A is "the cost of B given A, and the cost of C given A and B". So if *these* costs depend on the previous states, things get even more complicated.

In the end, the complexity of this revised A* will grow until it becomes your algorithm, where every state depends potentially on the sequence of all preceding states. The more this is true, the more your algorithm is convenient; the more every state is a cost unto itself, the more A* is convenient.

And of course the possibility of closed loops (visiting the same state/action twice, making this a cyclic graph) blows A* straight out of the water.

Comment: It's definitely going to be a custom cost calculation that's probably rather complex. I can handle that part. I'm just wondering if I'm betting on the wrong horse with A* when I don't really have a heuristic function.